# Problem to access mysql using phpadmin interface (UBUNTU 20.04)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I'm a beginner in docker. I started a docker compose with mysql and phpmyadmin to do a simple test, but I have some problem to access MySQL server using phpMyAdmin interface.

I'm using UBUNTU 20.04

When I try access MySQL server with credentials in phpMyAdmin (http://localhost:9090/) I get this error:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Follow below also the docker log with error regardins phpmyadmin

```
phpmyadmin_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin_1  | [Sun Dec 19 12:12:17.249145 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.20 configured -- resuming normal operations
phpmyadmin_1  | [Sun Dec 19 12:12:17.249624 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Could you please help me understand if I need do some setup in my Ubuntu environment or if the docker-compose file is wrong?

Follow bellow my docker-compose.yaml

```
 version: '3.5'

 services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     ports:
       - 3306:3306
   environment:
     MYSQL_USER: root
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
   volumes:
     - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
   security_opt:
     - seccomp:unconfined

 phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
   links:
     - mysql
   ports:
     - 9090:80
   environment:
     - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

 rabbitmq:
   image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management
   ports:
     - 5672:5672
     - 15672:15672
   volumes:
    - $PWD/storage/rabbitmq1:/var/lib/rabbitmq
   environment:
     - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=This_is_my_secret_phrase
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
```

volumes:
mysql:
rabbitmq:
phpmyadmin:

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the text of the error, instead of a link to an image?  Is the RabbitMQ setup important to the question, or can you delete it?  How are you configuring the admin console to connect to the database?  Is there any application code that's part of this setup?

Comment: Hi David, I included the text error as you suggestion. Regarding RabbitMQ setup is import to my project. I believe that RabbitMQ does not contains error because when I try to upload the docker-compose service the RabbitMQ is working fine. I uploaded the docker logs in question also.

Answer (score 0):

Your phpMyAdmin container doesn't know where to find the MySQL database server. You need to:

- link the MySQL container (you already did that),
- supply a config file to phpMyAdmin, or
- provide proper connection details when logging in to phpMyAdmin.

All options of the Docker image are documented in [phpMyAdmin Docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin?tab=description).

In case of your specific docker-compose file, the connection details that work are:

[image]

Comment: Hi andrzwjwp, I tried included mysql:db in link line but not working. I updated my question with some error. maybe can help you understand the problem. thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, I double checked this and when you create a new stack using your exact docker-compose.yml - it works with the credentials and server name I provided in the screenshot. You don't even have to update the container link section of the yaml file.